# Check whether a record of given id exists in the store?

Tags: ember.js

In a property of a `TodoController`, how do i check whether a record of type `todo` and given id exists in the store?

I use the LocalStorage adapter.

A fiddle (the `parentId` property in setter mode should do the described check): http://jsbin.com/UDoPajA/201/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a 404 response is used when a record isn't found.  In this particular instance you're using an extremely old version of Ember and Ember Data.  So in a general use case you would do it like so:

```
this.store.find('color', 1).then(function(record){
  console.log('record', record);
}, function(error){
  console.log('error', error);
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/572/edit